# Matlab: Gauss Elimination Function

Tags: matlab

```
function x = Gauss_Elimination(A,b)

n = length(b);
x = zeros(n,1);

% Forward Elimination
for i = 1:n-1 

    for j = i+1:n

        mul = A(j,i)/A(i,i); % Multiplier

        for k = i+1:n

            A(j,k) = A(j,k) - mul*A(i,k);

        end

        b(j) = b(j) - mul*b(i);

    end

end

x(n) = b(n)/A(n,n); % Obtain solution for the last variable

% Back Substitution
for i = n-1:-1:1

    sum = b(i);

    for j = i+1:n

        sum = sum - A(i,j)*x(j);

    end

    x(i) = sum/A(i,i);

end
```

When A=[0 1 1 1;3 0 3 -4;1 1 1 2;2 3 1 3]; b=[0;7;6;6]; x=[4;-3;1;2]

However, x=[NAN;NAN;NAN;NAN] when I utilize this function.

Does somebody tell me the reason???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using breakpoints to see the value of the variables at each iteration. 
The problem is the variable "mul", you are dividing something/0->infinite. That is why you are getting those results. If you set

A=[2 1 1 1;3 4 3 -4;1 1 1 2;2 3 1 3]; b=[0;7;6;6]

you get as answer: 
ans =

-4.7273
    1.7273
    6.4545
    1.2727

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, sir. You give me a big help.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this code here

https://github.com/pavdpr/matlab-latex/blob/master/RRE.m

It does Gaussian elimination and then writes it out to LaTex. you can strip the writing out to Latex and just take a look at code that preforms the elimination.

And a python version of the same code if you want it

https://github.com/Maggick-/RRE2LaTeX/blob/master/RRE.py